# Method to convert large PDFs to text?

Tags: pdf, text, text-extraction, pdftotext

Can anyone suggest a method or library to convert **large** (100MB-4GB) PDFs to text programatically?

I normally use pdftotext (poppler-utils) but it shows an "Out of memory" message for large files, and only the first 6000 or so pages are in the output text file.

Maybe there's a way to split these PDFs up and then run pdftotext, maybe there are methods for successfully running more expensive calls without eating up memory, maybe another library is best... basically, I'd love to hear your suggestions. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

we are parsing newspapers and magazines from PDFs and converting them into JPEGs, not exactly the same, but we have that same problem out of memory, when opening and parsing but with imagemagick/ghostscript.

Our solution was to split them up to batches below 10 pages, parse one batch at a time, and then place the result in order, or for you append the text to where ever you are storing it.

you could probably use imagemagick/ghostscript to split them to smaller PDFs if pdftotext don't support that

Answer (score 0):

As you have thousands of pages inside input PDF files. Each page may contain text, images and other objects which are decompressed and may take up to x2 or more memory.

So you may split files by 3000 pages, like this:

1. split your source PDF files using

   - Using [Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com) via [PDFSplit](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~weimer/pdfsplit/pdfsplit) script from the command line:

`pdfsplit input.pdf 1 3000 output1-3000.pdf`

`pdfsplit input.pdf 3001 6000 output3001-6000.pdf`

2. Run `pdftotext` to convert pdf to text files;
3. And then finally merge output files:

`cat output1-3000.txt output3001-6000.txt > output-all-pages.txt`

You may also manually split files using [PDFSam](http://www.pdfsam.org) utility on step (1).